# Paragraph "view" access error

Tags: 8, users, paragraphs

I have a weird issue. I created a custom profile using the Profile module. This profile has some classic fields and some paragraph type fields. I assigned permissions to a role to create profiles and the user is able to do that. The problem is that this user (the owner/author of the profile) cannot view the paragraph fields when displaying the profile entity. He can edit fields but cannot view them. Other classic fields can be seen, but not paragraphs.

Anyone else had this problem?

I looked into the paragraph module and the message "You are not allowed to view this ..." is displayed when the user does not have "view" access to the paragraph entity. Which is weird because it does have access to view the parent entity (it is the author) and to edit all fields in it.

[image]

Comment: Paragraphs access depends on access to the parent entity and that they do not have the status set to false (hidden by default). Are you sure that the parent entity is really accessible and you didn't override something in a strange way?

Comment: Or that something is somehow setting the status to false by default, enable the field in manage form display and check it